# Duplicate Arrays in Object of Arrays four times and manipulate first Item in array dynamically with condictions

Tags: javascript

my object of arrays looks like this:

```
const foo  = {"data":[
[1,'asdf'],
[2,'lorem'],
[3,'impsum'],
[4,'test'],
[5,'omg'],
]}
```

i want to duplicate every array 4 times and manipulate the first item, like i ++0.1

the result should look like this:

```
const foo  = {"data":[
[1.1,'asdf'],
[1.2,'asdf'],
[1.3,'asdf'],
[1.4,'asdf'],
[2.1,'lorem'],
[2.2,'lorem'],
[2.3,'lorem'],
[2.4,'lorem'],
[3.1,'impsum'],
[3.2,'impsum'],
[3.3,'impsum'],
[3.4,'impsum'],
[4.1,'test'],
[4.2,'test'],
[4.3,'test'],
[4.4,'test'],
[5.1,'omg'],
[5.2,'omg'],
[5.3,'omg'],
[5.4,'omg'],
]}
```

Comment: You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). To get the best answers to your question we like to see a) that you've attempted to solve the problem yourself first, and b) used a [mcve] to narrow down the problem. Asking SO to do all the work for you doesn't help you or us. [Here's a question checklist you might find useful.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignoring the wrapper object for simplicity, how about this?

```js
const data = [
  [1, 'asdf'],
  [2, 'lorem'],
  [3, 'impsum'],
  [4, 'test'],
  [5, 'omg'],
];

const out = data.map(([ num, ...rest ]) => {
  return Array(4).fill(0).map((_, idx) => {
    return [ num + ((idx + 1) / 10), ...rest ];
  });
}).flat(1);

console.log(out);
```

You could even do this in a one liner! *

```js
data.map(([ num, ...rest ]) => Array(4).map((_, index) => ([ num + ((index + 1) / 10), ...rest ]))).flat(1);
```

* *Please don’t.*

---

**EDIT:** An explanation of the above, because there’s a lot going on in those few lines.

We start with a call to [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
data.map((...) => { ... })
```

This creates a new array with the same length as `data`, but each element is passed through the [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) (*just a less verbose way of writing `function(...) { ... }`*) before being added to the new array.

Before we dive into the body of that function, let’s take a closer look at its parameter:

```js
([ num, ...rest ]) => { ... }

// Or in regular function syntax:
function ([ num, ...rest ]) { ... }
```

There are two things going on here: [array destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Array_destructuring) and the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax). These are two powerful new features in ES6. Array destructuring is a way of assigning values in an array to individual variables without first creating a local variable to store the array itself.

Our function here takes only one parameter (an array) but there are *two* variables accessible from within the function body. *Neither of these is the entire array though.*

- The first is `num`, which holds the value of the first element in the array.
- The second is `rest`, which holds the remainder of the values in the array. The spread syntax is used here to indicate “*the rest of the values*”. It doesn’t matter if there are 2 or 20 elements in the array, `rest` will contain all of them except the first (which is in `num`).

In the body of the mapping function, we start with this:

```js
Array(4)
```

[`Array()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Syntax) is simply the constructor for javascript’s underlying `Array` type. When called with a single numerical parameter, it initialises the array to that length.

Then we use `Array.map()` again, this time on the new array we’ve just created:

```js
Array(4).map((_, idx) => { ... })
```

Notice this time the function we pass as a parameter to `map` takes *two* parameters: `_` and `idx`. The first is the same as before, the current element of the array we’re processing. Since the array is currently empty, we’ll ignore this one (hence its name). The second is the index in the array of the current element - this is what we’re going to use to derive the new value for `num`:

```js
num + ((idx + 1) / 10)
```

This expression takes the original of `num` for this ‘group’ of new element and adds the decimal part to it, based on the current index of the inner array.

The new `num` is then returned, along with the rest of the array values we stored earlier in `rest`:

```js
return [ num + ((idx + 1) / 10), ...rest ];
```

Here we use the spread operator again to indicate that `rest` should not just be returned as another element in the array, but that every element in `rest` should be added to the returned array.

So this entire inner section returns an array of arrays for a single new ‘group’ of elements:

```js
return Array(4).map((_, idx) => {
  return [ num + ((idx + 1) / 10), ...rest ];
});

// Return example:
[
  [ 1.1, "asdf" ],
  [ 1.2, "asdf" ],
  [ 1.3, "asdf" ],
  [ 1.4, "asdf" ],
]
```

Adding the outer wrapper back in gives us:

```js
data.map(([ num, ...rest ]) => {
  return Array(4).fill(0).map((unused, idx) => {
    return [ num + ((idx + 1) / 10), ...rest ];
  });
})

// Return example:
[
  [
    [ 1.1, "asdf" ],
    [ 1.2, "asdf" ],
    [ 1.3, "asdf" ],
    [ 1.4, "asdf" ],
  ],
  [
    [ 2.1, "lorem" ],
    [ 2.2, "lorem" ],
    [ 2.3, "lorem" ],
    [ 2.4, "lorem" ],
  ],
  ...
]
```

We’ve now got the right values, but there’s an extra layer of arrays here we don’t want. You’ve probably noticed the final bit of code already:

```js
.flat(1)
```

[`Array.flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) *flattens* the array to the specified depth. For a depth of `1`, this means it takes every array *directly inside* the outer array and adds its elements to that outer array. For a depth of `n`, this is repeated on the output of the previous iteration `n` times. If we used a depth of `2` here, the output would be a single array like this:

```js
[ 1.1, "asdf", 1.2, "asdf", ... ]
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
var i = 0;
var j = 0
foo.data[0][i].forEach(function(foo){
   while (j < 3){
      foo.data[0][i].push(foo);
       j++
   }
   i++
})
```